# Type checking of a self-defined function

Tags: haskell

I got this function:

```
foo [] = []
foo (x:xs) = foo us ++ foo ys
where us = filter (<=x) xs
      ys = filter (>=x) xs
```

type of this function is Ord a => [a] -> [b] .

I don't understand why the output type is [b] and not [a]. I think it should be [a] since the elements of the output list will be part of the elements of the input list.

I am using Hugs, but I don't think it changes anything.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The type `Ord a => [a] -> [b]` is internally consistent, though!

The problem is that you never actually add any elements from the input list to the output list.  You need a base case; something like `foo [x] = [x]`.  As it stands, you never actually say that any elements from the input list get added to the output list; the result of this function will always be `[]`, which can have type `[b]` regardless of input.

If you're trying to implement something like Quicksort here, though, there are two logical problems in your implementation:

1. `x`, the pivot, doesn't get added to the output list.
2. Any values in the list that are equal to `x` other than `x` itself will be added twice, once from `us` and once from `ys`.

Comment: I'll add this to my list of categories of bugs that could be discovered if the compiler could warn about type signatures that are less polymorphic than they could be.

Comment: thanks! actually it's just an exercise in which I need to figure out the type. I'm not using that particular function.